# The tag [transparentdataencryption] is a synonym of [tde] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[tde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tde) (with wiki; 25 Q) is about Transparent Data Encryption which is the same as [transparentdataencryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transparentdataencryption) (no wiki; 14 Q).

I don't think it can be handled by the community. So, are some diamonds around?

I would like to make it a synonym instead of burninating, because it helps in finding the right tag. Otherwise it will be created anew.

Comment: Surely, it should be [transparent-data-encryption], not [transparentdataencryption].